# How to change Icon spacing or disable Icon grid on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: icons, 19.04

I am trying to adjust the Ubuntu 19 Desktop to look more like Ubuntu 18. There I could move the icons wherever I wanted. It had a horizontal grid but not vertical, so icons could be dragged together into clusters. Ubuntu 19 seem to have an icon grid similar to windows. Any way to disable it? Or at least configure icon spacing?

Answer (score 0):

Using a script called iconic that lets you define a grid size larger than the icons and sort them by different criteria1.
Installing nemo as an alternative file manager and desktop manager and turning off “use-desktop-grid” in org/nemo/desktop via dconf-editor2.
Right-clicking on the desktop and selecting Keep aligned to fill the gaps in the grid3.